# How to push the Tag to GitHub from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, repository, github-api

Here are the steps I have followed to push my Tag to GitHub Remote Repository. But not able to get Tag on other user's eclipse. (I have successfully uploaded my Repository and able to commit the changes.)

1. Right click **Repository** in Eclipse Package Explorer.
2. Go to **Team -> Advanced -> Tag**
3. Filling up all details and clicked a **OK**. This will Tag in my Local System.
4. Now, Right click again **Repository** in Eclipse.
5. Go to **Team -> Show in Repository View**. Git Repositories window will appear.
6. In that select the **Tag** and click **Push Tag**.
7. Entering all the details. I am able to get the message window without any error. But still not able to get a Tagged version on other User's PC.

What am I still missing? I had see the command prompt versions Help on GitHub. But dont want to use that... I want to make it with UI only...

Can anyone help me out.... thanks in advance...

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my setup to simulate what you have.

1. An instance of Eclipse Indigo SR2 on OSX with Egit installed (from **[here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F)**). This is the 'source' machine from which I'll create the tag according to your steps.

   1.1 Setup GITHUB in the above using **[this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github)**.
2. An instance of Eclipse Indigo SR2 on Ubuntu running inside a VM. This is the 'other client' which shall try to get the tag once it's pushed to GITHUB.

I'll be back with what I learnt from this experience.

**Update**

So, I followed your steps to push a tag on one Eclipse and then pull it from another Eclipse instance. I was able to do so successfully.

I have created a screencast to show what I did. Watch it **[here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6E9alq-5ls)** and let me know if it gives you any ideas about what you might be doing differently ?

Comment: Only one thing i was missing is instead of clicking on Tag and then Push Tag... I have to create new Tag by right clicking on Tags. This is absolutely good.... Thanks for your video and Time.... Much more appreciated +1...

Comment: @MacMini-iOS, absolutely my pleasure :). Glad the vid helped sort out the problem. I have only ever used GIT on command-line, so exploring eGIT was interesting. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. Is not there some more simple solution? Was using Mercurial with Eclipse and tagging was much much simpler: just selecting Tag menu item, choosing tag name and doing regular Push.

Answer (score 0):

Note: with [EGit 3.2](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/3.2#Features) (December 2013), you now can push specific tags (insteald of *all* the tags).

> Push Tags wizard simplifies pushing one or multiple tags

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/0/03/Egit-3.2-PushTagWizard.png]